# How to avoid the flash when switching streams in webrt?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, webrtc, video-processing

The following code is to test the performance when switching the localVideo.src to different streams in webrtc. There is a flash in the video element when its source switching from stream1 to stream2.

Is there a way to avoid the flash? like when we watch youtube videos and change its quality, the screen will pause and then play without flash. As what i have learnt, it is actually switching to another video.

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (stream1) {
  self.localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream1);
  self.stream2 = stream;
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log("switch to stream 2");
    self.localVideo.src  = window.URL.createObjectURL(self.stream2);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: More info please! What browser and hardware? Also, where does `stream` come from and what does it contain? This is going to be heavily browser and hardware dependent, e.g. I don't see any flash in Firefox on OSX switching between a camera and a screen capture. Phone hardware in particular may not let you open two cameras at once, leaving you with no option but to flash for a split second.

Comment: Also, try `src.localVideo.srcObject = stream1` instead of the blob url hack. Even Chrome Canary finally supports this.